# dynamic json to combobox dojo

Tags: javascript, json, combobox, dojo

I have a problem with filling a Combobox dynamic with a jsonRest from a cross Origin request.

I found a chance to do it static (I hope this is the right vocabulary), but I don’t figured out how to do it for more than one case.Because this is a little part of a bigger Website with five Comboboxes.

Here's the Code

```
require([
"dojo/_base/array",
"dojo/store/Memory",
"dojo/store/JsonRest",  
"dijit/form/ComboBox", 
"dojo/store/Cache",
"dojo/store/Observable",
"dijit/form/Textarea",
"dojo/domReady!"
 ], 

function(array, Memory, JsonRest, ComboBox, Cache, Observable, Textarea){

var myArray = new Array;
var myStore = new Observable (new Cache (new JsonRest ({
            target: “URL / target”,
            idProperty: "WA",
            headers: { "X-Requested-With": "" }
        }), new Memory ()));
var myTextarea = new Textarea ({
    name: "myarea",
    style: "width:200px;"
}, "myarea");
myStore.query().then(function(response){
            });

store = new Memory({data: myArray});        //Store anlegen ... mit Array befüllen

var comboBoxWA = new ComboBox({
    id: "comboWA",
    name: "WA",
    value: "",
    store: store, // übergabe angelegter Store zu Combobox
    searchAttr: "WA"
}, "comboWA");

// Array befüllen,.. Store anlegen,... Array dem Store zuweisen
myStore.query().then(function(response){
    dojo.forEach( response, function( obj ) {
        for (var p in obj) {
            if(p=="WA"){
```

//Here is my Problem, I can’t change the “WA” in myArray.push to some global Variable.

```
                myArray.push({"WA" : obj[p]});  //Array befüllen
                console.debug(myArray.toSource()); 
      }}
      });
        });
 });
```

The json response looks like this
[Object { WA=‘'WA_30_14"}, Object { WA="WA_30_12"} , Object { WA="WA_30_10"}, Object { WA="WA_30_16"},…]

Have anybody an Idea or a simple example for me?
Thanks, Georg

Comment: do you require "myArray.push({"WA" : obj[p]});" to be  "myArray.push({some_global_variable: obj[p]});". If so then just decalre the global variable and add it to the statement as  "myArray.push({some_global_variable: obj[p]});" it should work. Do not put quotes around the some_global_variable. You can check the value of the global variable before using push method. say console.log("My glogbal varible"+some_global_variable) to check the values of the variable.

Comment: You can also try the below method. if the above does not work.o you require "myArray.push({"WA" : obj[p]});" to be  "myArray.push({some_global_variable: obj[p]});".
do the following.
1.create an empty LOCAL object before the push method
2.Use the array syntax for assiging the property to the local variable
3.Pass the local variable as parameter to the push method.
var localobj = {}; // step 1
localobj[global_obj] = obj[p]; //step 2
myArray.push(localobj); // step 3
You can check the value of the global variable before using push() using the  console.log("My glogbal varible"+global_variable)

Comment: the problem is: if i write "myArray.push({some_global_variable: obj[p]});" it write [Object { some_global_variable="MB_30_14"}, Object { some_global_variable="MB_30_12"} ,...

Comment: did you try the second comment?

Comment: `var localobj = {};` // step 1   `localobj[global_var] = obj[p];` //step 2 `myArray.push(localobj);` // step 3

Comment: please accept the answer. so that it would be useful to someone else who visits the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the below method. so you require "myArray.push({"WA" : obj[p]});" to be "myArray.push({some_global_variable: obj[p]});". 
do the following. 
1.create an empty LOCAL object before the push method 
2.Use the array syntax for assiging the property to the local variable
 
3.Pass the local variable as parameter to the push method.

```
var localobj = {}; // step 1 
localobj[global_var] = obj[p]; //step 2 
myArray.push(localobj); // step 3
```

You can check the value of the global variable before using push() using

```
console.log("My glogbal varible"+global_var);
```